# Remove Image of First Frame of Video in UIImageView before playing video in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video which gets played in a MPMoviePlayerController. I have set the background color of the MPMoviePlayerController to clearColor.

In order to display the first frame of the given video, I am using a UIImageView below the MPMoviePlayerController to display the first frame.

When the user clicks on the play button, I remove the given image from the super view using the following code inside the method moviePlaybackStarted:

```
[imageView removeFromSuperview];
```

This I have put inside a Notification method, for which I have used the following code.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackStarted:)  
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification  
                                               object:self.videoPlayer];
```

The problem is that, when I remove the UIImage from the imageView object, there appears a black screen before the movie starts playing.

If I dont remove the imageView object from the superview, then that black screen does not appear. But I have to remove it from the superview.

Where should I remove the imageView from the superview so that I do not get the black screen before the video starts playing. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Actully u wanna to cahnge the background image not the image view , so u have to set the different  image over imageView at different conditions. by this way ur background image will not look black.
like:

[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"]];